# RPi4 Ubuntu 20.04 mouse conflict FIDECO M.2 PCIe NVME enclosure and Samsung Memorie MZ-V7S1T0 970 EVO Plus SSD

Tags: usb, 20.04, mouse, raspberrypi

I am on RPi4 Ubuntu 20.04 desktop and have mouse conflict between any mouse and Samsung Memorie MZ-V7S1T0 970 EVO Plus SSD da 1 TB, PCIe NVMe M.2 inside FIDECO M.2 PCIe NVME enclosure USB 3.

If I plug in the Fideco my whole system freezes and the mouse hides (if it's plugged in)

If the mouse is not plugged in there is no problem.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: it's a power problem.

I have mouse, keyboard and fan on GPIO.

If I disconnect the fan I can connect usb-ssd without losing the mouse.

So I bought an external powered USB 3 hub.